# Is it undefined behavior to change the pointer which is pointed by unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, pointers, unique-ptr

Performing reset() on the unique_ptr's raw pointer that was gotten via get() is undefined behavior, it's like:

```
   std::unique_ptr<int> thing(new int(8));
   int* other = thing.get();
   other.reset(new int(15));
```

But what if the raw pointer of unique_ptr can point to the object of the same type? For example given the following code

```
class Node {
    public:
        std::unique_ptr<Node> previous;
        std::unique_ptr<Node> next;
        int data;        
        Node(int d) : previous(nullptr),
                      next(nullptr),   
                      data(d) {}
};

void some_function(std::unique_ptr<Node> node, Node* other_ptr) {
    Node* node_ptr = node.get();
    node_ptr->next.reset(other_ptr); // ***           
    ………………………………………………………………………………….
    ………………………………………………………………………………….
   // Some code. Please don't focus on the secondary things.
   // The main question whether it allowed to perform reset from line ****)
}
```

Is this undefined behavior too? If yes why.

the link of the code: [Code](https://ideone.com/e.js/pawlyc!)

Comment: You can't do `.reset` on a *raw pointer*. It's not undefined behavior, it's a compile error.

Comment: Nonsense aside, I think the answer depends on _who (if anytone) owns_ `other_ptr`. Currently your claiming ownership of it with `reset(other_ptr)`, so it had better not be owned anywhere else.

Comment: @std_name Heres: `int* other ... other.reset( ...`

Comment: @std: Your example code produces: `..\main.cpp:7:12: error: request for member 'reset' in 'other', which is of non-class type 'int*'`

Comment: I think you very much misunderstand `unique_ptr`. When you pass `node` by value to `some_function`, it will be destroyed and the contained pointer will be deleted inside that function. `node_ptr->next` is completely superfluous and can be replaced with `node->next`. Also, `some_function` is declared to return `Node* but there is no return statement.

Comment: how is `int` not the same type as `int` ? I dont understand what is the difference between the two examples

Comment: Regarding the edited question, the line `node_ptr->next.reset(other_ptr)` is fine _as long as_ A) `other_ptr` was allocated using `new` and B) `other_ptr` will not be `delete`d anywhere else (whether manually or by another smart pointer). But there are some weird features of your code that are still very distracting.

Comment: @MFnx Actually it would need to be `some_function(std::move(some_unique_pointer), ...)` or `some_function(create_unique_pointer(), ...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With following preconditions, the behaviour of `some_function` is well defined:

- `other_ptr` must have been allocated using `new`, and still be valid (not deleted).
- Ownership of `other_ptr` must have been transferred<sup>1</sup> to the function i.e. nothing else owns it.
- `node` must not be null.

However, `node`, like all arguments, is local to the function. When the function ends, `node` is destroyed. Consequently, the pointer it manages is deleted. Thus it seems *pointless* to modify the pointed object, which is what the function does.

<sup>1</sup> It is a bad idea to transfer ownership using a bare pointer. You should instead use unique pointer to transfer ownership.

---

P.S. With the `next` and `previous` pointers, `Node` looks a lot like a doubly linked list. It cannot be a list however, because the previous node and the next node cannot possibly both have unique ownership of the current node.

P.P.S. `Node* node_ptr = node.get(); node_ptr->next.reset...` can be simplified into `node->next.reset`.

Comment: Thank for the answer